# How to ignore a scape of a word character in a python string with two consecutive apostrophe

Tags: string, escaping, unicode-escapes, raw

[Escape Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTZxq.png)

Hello all,

I have the bellow python string and I am trying to basically to ignore the **''** scape characters. My Goal is to have the two single apostrophe before and after the DD but the raw string is not working as expected as seen in the image. Is there a way I could make them appear as I am expecting ?

```
r"""hello my name is "John" I cannot remove ''DD'' the escape character in order to show 
the two single quotes together"""
```

Thanks,

I tried using replacements functions and other methods that I researched and non worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
chars = r""""John" ''DD''"""
chars                         # '"John" \'\'DD\'\''
```

> ```
> '"John" \'\'DD\'\''
> ```

Above you see escaped inner single quotes (apostrophes) because the *output is **presented** as [single-quoted string](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str)*. In fact, there are no reverse solidi (backslashes) in the `chars` string:

```
len(chars)      # 13
print( chars)   # "John" ''DD''
```

> ```
> "John" ''DD''
> ```

Another proof (`chars` string as a sequence characters):

```
import unicodedata
for jj, char in enumerate( chars):
    print( f'{jj:3}', char, unicodedata.name(char,'???'))
```

> ```
>   0 " QUOTATION MARK
>   1 J LATIN CAPITAL LETTER J
>   2 o LATIN SMALL LETTER O
>   3 h LATIN SMALL LETTER H
>   4 n LATIN SMALL LETTER N
>   5 " QUOTATION MARK
>   6   SPACE
>   7 ' APOSTROPHE
>   8 ' APOSTROPHE
>   9 D LATIN CAPITAL LETTER D
>  10 D LATIN CAPITAL LETTER D
>  11 ' APOSTROPHE
>  12 ' APOSTROPHE
> ```

Read more about escaping in [String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/lexical_analysis.html?highlight=strings#string-and-bytes-literals)